# When a thread is suspended after trying to acquire a lock, is there always a context switch?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

In the book [*Java Concurrency in Practice*](https://jcip.net/) by Brian Goetz et al.:

> Context switches are not free; thread scheduling requires manipulating shared data structures
> in the OS and JVM. The OS and JVMuse the same CPUs your program does; more CPU
> time spent in JVM and OS code means less is available for your program. But OS and JVM
> activity is not the only cost of context switches. When a new thread is switched in, the data
> it needs is unlikely to be in the local processor cache, so a context switch causes a flurry of
> cache misses, and thus threads run a little more slowly when they are first scheduled. This is
> one of the reasons that schedulers give each runnable thread a certain minimum time quantum
> even when many other threads are waiting: it amortizes the cost of the context switch and
> its consequences over more uninterrupted execution time, improving overall throughput (at
> some cost to responsiveness).

Is it possible to block a thread waiting for a lock without doing a context switch (not switching in another thread)? It seems that it could be useful since context switches are expensive.

Second question: does Thread.sleep() in Java trigger a context switch?

Comment: Not necessarily. We have multicore systems these days.

Comment: I wonder how virtual threads ([fibers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_(computer_science))) in [*Project Loom*](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/loom/Main) affect the issues raised in this Question.

Comment: but even if you get an answer, what are you going to do with that? that is far too low level to care, imo. instead I think it is far better to focus on getting things right, synchronization wise

Comment: Please don't ask 3 questions at once. Just ask one. You can edit the question.

Comment: Since you can't run code from that thread, and you don't want to run code from another thread (because it would pollute caches and so on), what can you possibly do that's useful exactly?

Comment: Context switches aren't "expensive", they are "not free". Delaying other threads by not allowing them to continue processing will be more expensive in almost all circumstances.

Comment: Suspending implies a context switch. But all common lock implementations have a spinning phase whose length depends on some heuristics before asking for suspension. That works smoothly if the lock owner runs on a different CPU core and releases the lock during the spinning phase. Otherwise, there wouldn’t be any point in trying to avoid suspension.

Comment: @BasilBourque virtual threads may have lower suspension costs when giving up the native thread to another virtual thread. That’s still not for free, on the other hand, if the current lock owner is another virtual thread using the same executor that suspension might be even required. But that’s not so different to the current situation. Spinning only makes sense when the current lock owner runs on another core concurrently and will release the lock during the spinning phase.

Answer (score 3):

There are lock mechanism that do not require context switches e.g. [Spinlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock):

> A spinlock is a lock which causes a thread trying to acquire it to simply wait in a loop ("spin") while repeatedly checking if the lock is available. Since the thread remains active but is not performing a useful task, the use of such a lock is a kind of busy waiting.
>
> [...]
>
> Because they avoid overhead from operating system process rescheduling or context switching, spinlocks are efficient if threads are likely to be blocked for only short periods. For this reason, operating-system kernels often use spinlocks. However, spinlocks become wasteful if held for longer durations, as they may prevent other threads from running and require rescheduling.

It all depends on your use case e.g. spinlocks might be useful in a real time systems while in a regular server-side application with multiple threads a regular lock will be more efficient.

Comment: under contention, a spinlock is a very bad idea

Comment: @Eugene Used at the right places, a spinlock is a very good idea, especially under contention.

Comment: @akuzminykh which is by far, not easy, to get right. most people should stay away from it - I mostly consider myself such person.

Comment: @Eugene I'm very sure that you've used spinlocks successfully already, from the answers I've seen by you. ^^ E.g. synchronization using CAS, which is what e.g. `AtomicInteger` and others do, are effectively using the concept "spinlock".

Comment: @Eugene, the problem with spin locks is, what happens if one thread is preempted while it's holding the lock, and another thread wants the lock? There's going to be a whole lot of spinning.  But what's the probablility of that happening? If you design your code to only hold the lock only just long enough to switch out a pointer or to increment a variable, and if the scheduling grain is on the order of ten milliseconds, then the probability is _very_ small. Small enough that the benefit of the lightweight spin lock can outweigh the harm from the occasional bad collision.

Comment: @SolomonSlow agreed + excellent comment. that is why I _do_ see benefit in spinlocks that are based on `CAS`. I should have made my first comment a lot cleaner, but it's too late to edit

Comment: @Eugene Make it an answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an un-popular opinion: very often you want context switching to happen. Imagine that there would be a way to prevent that, so every time a thread that needs to be taken away from the `CPU` would actually just stall, it means everyone else would effectively wait, like a `queue`; without given a chance to run.

Fast forward to our prod and we have `pod`s that have on purpose one `CPU` bound to them. If context switch would have been disabled somehow, we would not have liked that. I am OK with the context switch penalty for (almost) concurrent requests; in exchange for a single `CPU` provided to a `pod` (this isn't cheap in `AWS/OpenShift` or the like, especially when you multiply by hundreds).

There are cases where such a scenarios might be wanted, but they don't make the rule. One exception that I am aware of (and have done it myself) is to use a spinlock based on `CAS`, like `AtomicInteger` and friends (that have this build in internally).

I am pretty sure that increment via `CAS` will be cheaper than context switch. That being said, there is `LongAdder` that says in the documentation:

> But under high contention, expected throughput of this class is significantly higher, at the expense of higher space consumption.

So I guess there is simply no size fits all approach.

`Thread::sleep` *might* issue a context switch (and most probably does), but there are no guarantees.  This is not documented to do that, at least.

Comment: "Thread::sleep might issue a context switch (and most probably does), but there are no guarantees"
So in general any blocking operation (e.g. Thread::sleep, BlockingQueue::take) can either suspend the thread or use a spinlock. Is the decision to suspend or spinlock made by the OS, or is it made in the implementation of the method?

Comment: @alfer as far as I know, there are heuristics for what gets done, like a slow path and a fast path. If sleep is very short, there is a spinlock, if it is bigger, there is an actual park, and there is a context switch there.